# Ruby advanced active record queries across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord

I'm fairly new and am coming across a problem as I progress in the application I'm working on.

I have the following relationships set up

**game**

```
belongs_to :challenge  
has_many :game_players, through: :playersessions, source: :user  
has_many :playersessions
```

**challenge**

```
has_many :phrases
has_many :games
```

**phrase**

```
has_many :playedphrases
has_many :playersessions, through: :playedphrases
```

**playedphrase**

```
belongs_to :playersession
belongs_to :phrase
```

**playersession**

```
has_many :playedphrases
has_many :phrases, through: :playedphrases
```

All these relationships are working in my program, but I need to start doing some more advanced querying.  For instance, I would like to find the remaining phrases.  In english it would be "find this Game's Challenge's Phrases and remove the this Game's Playersession's Phrases". I believe the problem lies in the fact that @game.challenge.phrases returns Phrase objects and @game.playersessions must be iterated through to find all the phrase objects.

Any guidance on how to handle this type of query? Please let me know if any other info would help out.

Comment: Thank you @skram, still learning best practices here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a way to make this work - I don't know if it is the most eloquent ruby, but it works.

```
       def determine_remaining_phrases
            remain = @game.challenge.phrases

            @playersessions.each do |session|
                remain -= session.phrases
            end

            return remain
        end
```

Basically I needed to iterate through the playersessions and remove the associated phrases each pass through.  This leaves me with an array of phrase objects.  If someone has a more eloquent answer, please let me know.